# ¿Cómo recortar una cadena de texto con el comando "sed"?

Tags: bash, sed, grep

Quiero tratar la siguiente cadena (con una tabulación al principio):

```
    inet 192.168.0.20 netmask 0xfffffc00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
```

Que es la salida del siguiente comando:

```
ifconfig en0 | grep "inet "
```

El caso es que me gustaría poder quedarme únicamente con la IP y la única manera que lo he logrado ha sido haciendo lo siguiente:

```
ifconfig en0 | grep "inet " | sed "s/[[:space:]]inet //" | sed "s/ netmask.*//"
```

Como veis, utilizo hasta dos veces el comando `sed`, cosa que me gustaría evitar y poder hacerlo todo en una misma ejecución. Entiendo que con algún otro tipo de expresión regular mi duda quedaría resuelta pero no soy capaz de dar con ella.

¡Gracias, un saludo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

podrias hacerlo mas facil con el comando `cut`

```
ifconfig en0 | grep "inet " | cut -d " " -f2
```

> puedes usar `-f4` para la mascara y `-f6` para el broadcast
>   o en cadena con -f 2,4,6

manual:
[cut manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html)

con el comando awk:

```
ifconfig en0 | grep "inet " | awk '{print $2}'
```

> puedes usar y `$4` para la mascara y `$6` para el broadcast

manual awk:
[awk manual](http://fcaglp.unlp.edu.ar/~observacional/manuales/awk.pdf)

Comment: ¡Genial! Así es mucho más optimo y limpio. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Al usar `awk` puedes prescindir de "`grep`" y hacer todo en un paso:

```
ifconfig en0 | awk '/inet/{print $2}'
```

awk permite seleccionar lineas según su contenido y luego formatear.

Answer (score 0):

Está claro que para lo que busco es mucho más sencillo de la forma que comenta [Bryro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/61388/bryro) con el comando `cut`, pero dejo aquí dos formétodos que he encontrado con el comando `sed` sin necesidad de llamar a este mismo comando dos veces:

```
ifconfig en0 | grep "inet " | sed -e "s/[[:space:]]inet //" -e "s/ netmask.*//"
ifconfig en0 | grep "inet " | sed -e "s/[[:space:]]inet // ; s/ netmask.*//"
```

Aún así, está claro que debe haber una expresión regular que haga que se pueda hacer más compacto.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con un solo comando como con

**awk**

```
awk '/[[:space:]]inet/{print $2}'
```

O con una mejor regex.

```
awk '/inet[[:space:]][[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}/{print $2}'
```

Busca algo que sea de la forma "(1 o  tres digitos).(1 o  tres digitos).(1 o  tres digitos).(1 o  tres digitos)" que sea posterior a la cadena "inet " y luego, después de encontrar esa línea, imprime el segundo campo sin espacios.

**grep**

```
grep -Po '(?<=inet )[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}(?= netmask)'
```

Que imprime aquello que sea de la forma "(1 o  tres digitos).(1 o  tres digitos).(1 o  tres digitos).(1 o  tres digitos)" que esté en medio de las cadenas "inet " y " netmask"

o una variante útil en este caso.

```
grep -Po '(?<=inet ).*(?= netmask)'
```

Que imprime sólo lo que esté en medio de las palabras "inet " y " netmask"

**sed**

```
sed -nr 's/(.*inet )(.*)( netmask.*)/\2/p'
```

Que imprime sólo lo que esté en medio de las palabras "inet " y " netmask"